# ORM agnostic patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, orm

I am looking for a discussion on the use of ORMs in fashion where one could swap out the ORM you are using with a minimal impact on the rest of the system.

I guess if you were using MVP, your view and presenter would have no idea (no references) to whatever ORM you are using.  I think the best that I came up with is a Service class that uses some IRepository.  And the concrete repository returns DTOs to the service class.  You would have a concrete repository implementation for each ORM that you use.  I would also ask how you would manage the mappings between the ORM objects/entities and the DTOs efficiently.

I guess I would like to free the majority of the application from depending on a specific ORM.

Does anyone have a link to a blog/whitepaper discussing this topic?

Comment: "You Aren't Going to Need It", so "You Don't Need to Flag It".

Comment: This isn't really a discussion forum.  Is there an actual question here?

Comment: You really don't want to write ORM agnostic code.  Sure, you can get close, but it's not at all a pleasant experience to write the code or maintain it.  Just choose your ORM wisely.

Comment: @Don.  I guess I was looking for a link to a blog post or a whitepaper on the approach.

Comment: @jparram - Not to worry.  I think I was just in a bad mood.  It didn't get closed anyway, and there are a couple good posts.  If you edit the question, I think SO will let me retract my close vote, but it doesn't really matter much.

Comment: @Michael.  I can see how it could be unpleasant, but I would imagine it would be much more unpleasant if you were using, say, Entity Framework entities throughout your tiers and are one day tasked to remove them in favor of another orm.  This is obviously not appropriate for every application.  If the only part of your application that touched the ORM was the repository, then, the only part you would rewrite is the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, hiding the ORM used is a perfect job for the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

Comment: You wrote this a few seconds before I did :) :) Great answer!